# Parse Object has no data for this key when I login

Tags: java, android, authentication, parse-platform

I am trying to login with an user in Parse, but when I use the login Parse function I get the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data. ". This is a bit strange, because I have never had this error before when I login. I have not change any ParseUser. The code to login is the same that you can find in Parse Documentation.

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(nombre, pass, new LogInCallback() {

            public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user != null) {
                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.

                } else {
                    // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

StackTrace:

```
.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
04-18 12:15:28.611  27662-27662/droidotech.com.adaptavision W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.Parse$4$1.run(Parse.java:790)
04-18 12:15:28.612  27662-27662/droidotech.com.adaptavision W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
```

Comment: Can you add stack trace

Comment: StackTrace is high, I only have added this part, tell me if you need more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
In another class, I have a String value that call a get function in its declaration. You can not do this, you must call get function in the constructor or init method.

This is wrong:

```
private String TITLE = "This is the title" + getTitle();
```

This is the correct way:

```
private String TITLE;

public void init(String title){
   TITLE = "This is the title" + title;
}
```